# Google App Engine environment setup

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to setup the environment for Google App Engine in PHP. I have downloaded the SDK for PHP. And I have also downloaded the python 2.7.7 64 bit and installed both. I tried to run the hello world program from
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-guestbook/archive/phase0-helloworld.zip
and extracted it in a folder named helloworld(In this folder 3 files are stored app.yaml,helloworld.php,README.md)
then I added it and tried to run it. After running I get this error

[image]

can anyone help me? plz

Comment: Have you create your application in google app engine.    link = https://appengine.google.com/  ?

Comment: Looks like the error message is from clicking browse -- there must have also be an error in run given the icon next to "helloworld" -- look at the Logs (4th button from the left) to determine what's stopping your code from running; if that's not clear to you edit your Q to show the logs and your code (make sure they're nicely formatted!-) and we'll try to help, but on the information you present so far there's really not much we can say!

Answer (score 2):

This problem I faced because of the version of python I was using(3.4.2). It should be python 2.7 . Otherwise you will face this error.